# Tracking direct file downloads

Tags: download, matomo, goal-tracking

I have some files (.zip and .pkg) available for download on my website. I'd like to get statistics of downloads using Piwik.

I have created 'Download a file' goals for each file with 'where the filename contains FileToDownload.zip' criteria. Unfortunately, goals are not tracking because no PHP or JavaScript code executed when user clicks on file link.

I added `oncick="_paq.push(['trackGoal', NNN]);"` for each link. Now is a time to detect what goal number (NNN) should I use for each file to download.

How to get right number of goal for each download link? And how to automate this process for cases when lists of files and goals will be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is PHP code example joining together two databases for generating automatic JavaScript `onclick`events:

```
// Open website database and get list of files to download
$_db = @mysqli_connect($_dbhost, $_dbuser, $_dbpassword, $_dbname);
$data = @mysqli_query($_db, "SELECT * FROM downloads");
if ($data && @mysqli_num_rows($data)) while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
{
  $filename = $row['filename'];

  // Open Piwik database and get goal for this file
  $_pdb = @mysqli_connect($_pdbhost, $_pdbuser, $_pdbpassword, $_pdbname);
  $pdata = @mysqli_query($_pdb, "SELECT idgoal FROM piwik_goal WHERE match_attribute='file' AND pattern LIKE'%$filename' AND deleted=0");
  if ($pdata && $row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($pdata))
  {
    $goal = $row['idgoal'];
    $onclick = " onclick=\"_paq.push(['trackGoal', $goal]);\"";
  }
  echo "<a href="downloads/$filename"$onclick>$filename</a>";
}
```